# How to unbind other checkboxes change event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxes in a multiple rows.As I have already posted the question, how to enable or disable the icon based on checkboxes status. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549999/how-to-enable-or-disable-a-image-based-on-the-checkbox-value-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment60702059_36549999
What my solution is , giving a same class to every checkbox in a all rows. adding a user defined attribute common to each row and making a relation with row icon.

I have tried below code

```
  //html 



     <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">Summary/td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="1" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="2" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon"></td>

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="3" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon"></td>
            <td><a id="SummaryEditIcon"><img href="#"></a></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">Model/td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="1" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="2" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon"></td>

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="3" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon"></td>
            <td><a id="ModelEditIcon"><img href="#"></a></td>
        </tr>
```

// js

```
$(".allCheckboxes").unbind.change(function(){

        var editIconId =$(this).attr("data-editIcon");
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("#"+editIconId).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $("#"+editIconId).prop("disabled",true);
            checkAndEnableEditIcon(editIconId);
        }
    });
});
function checkAndEnableEditIcon(editIconId)
{
    var count = 0;
    $(".allCheckboxes").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("data-editIcon") == editIconId)
        {
            count++;
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                $("#"+editIconId).removeAttr("disabled");
                return;
            }
        }
        if(count == 3)
        {
          return;
        }
    });
}
```

The above code is not working.. i could not recognize the problem.Can anyone solve this please.

Comment: `$(".allCheckboxes").off('change').change(function(){})`

Comment: yea..but at the current state if in a row any one of the check box is checked,then only icon must be displayed... The above code not even performing at current stage as well as after unchecking all the checkboxes

Comment: why do you need to unbind? i think you can achieve what you want in normal way

Comment: when should the icon be enabled?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks many things are wrong in many ways. First look:

1. HTML Rows, closing  tag `/td>` is incorrect on first cell, both rows. Change to `</td>`.
2. JQuery Code should be `.unbind()`, not just `.unbind`
3. `$(".allCheckboxes")` does not exist in your HTML. Did you mean `$(".allchecks")`?

Not sure if this is your intention: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lw7nvgsr/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">Summary</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="1" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="2" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="3" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <a id="SummaryEditIcon"><img href="#"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">Model</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="1" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="2" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="3" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <a id="ModelEditIcon"><img href="#"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".allchecks").unbind().change(function() {
    var editIconId = $(this).attr("data-editIcon");
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      console.log("Enabling " + editIconId);
      $("#" + editIconId).removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      console.log("Disabling " + editIconId);
      $("#" + editIconId).prop("disabled", true);
      checkAndEnableEditIcon(editIconId);
    }
  });

  function checkAndEnableEditIcon(editIconId) {
    var count = 0;
    $(".allchecks").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("data-editIcon") == editIconId) {
        count++;
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
          $("#" + editIconId).removeAttr("disabled");
          return;
        }
      }
      if (count == 3) {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Even with these changes, I suspect none of that is working the way you want it to and that is more of a logic issue than a code issue. You state in your other post, "*if any one of the checkbox is checked , a image on that corresponding row must be displayed.*" This did not make a lot of sense to me until I read over it a number of times. I think what you mean is that if any one of the checkboxes in that row is checked, after the change event, the image for that row would become visible.

To get this, you should have taken the advice of those in the last post: *1) How to get value of checkbox? 2) How to hide/show image? Search for them on SO or Google - there is plenty of answers. – Alexander Trakhimenok*. Check the value of each checkbox, and then show/hide an image. This is one way to do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lw7nvgsr/4/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">Summary</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="1" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="2" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="3" data-editIcon="SummaryEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <a id="SummaryEditIcon" href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-finance-11/100/icon-37-128.png" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">Model</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="1" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="2" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="allchecks" checked="checked" name="Summary" value="3" data-editIcon="ModelEditIcon">
    </td>
    <td>
      <a id="ModelEditIcon" href="#"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/summary_318-101407.png"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".allchecks").change(function(e) {
    loopRow($(this).parent().parent());
  });

  function loopRow(r) {
    console.log("Checking Row " + r[0].rowIndex);
    var showImg = false;
    $(r).find(".allchecks").each(function(k, v) {
      if ($(v).is(":checked")) {
        console.log("Found Check in row ", r);
        showImg = true;
      }
    });
    if (showImg) {
      $(r).find("td:last-child img").show();
    } else {
      $(r).find("td:last-child img").hide();
    }
  }

  $("table tr").each(function() {
    loopRow($(this));
  });
});
```

Don't bother remaking the wheel. Make use of the tools available to you. When a checkbox is changed, loop through all the checkboxes in that row, see if a checkbox `.is(":checked")`. This will return `true` or `false`, so flag it if you find any one checkbox checked.

If all 3 are unchecked, the flag will remain false and the image will be hidden. If you want, you can `.remove()` and `.append()` the image in and out. Another method to keep the flow and rendering is to toggle the `visible` attribute via CSS.

Lastly, I loop each row in the table when the page loads and check for checks in each row.